# Alamofire Cellular Network "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009"

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

When i use my application on wifi there is no problem but if i change my network as 3g or 4g it is only say "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009"

How to fix that problem?

Comment: cant really say whats going wrong unless you provide more information or how you used almofire

Comment: Could you post the code how you use the Alamofire since Alamofire didn't have problem with it

Comment: i am not sure alamofire. i could be diffrent problem. it is work on wireless.

Answer (score 0):

The error code `-1009` means that the device is not connected to the internet. However, as it is an `NSURLErrorDomain` error, it should not be the problem with Alamofire, it is that your device is really not connected to the network. Make sure that you can load webpages like Google.

Comment: yes i am sure, i have internet on my phone because i am wrote this question from my phone :)

Comment: hello, do you have any news on this ? A user of mine has the same problem : he can Google but when he try to use my app the code -1009 says he don't have internet ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still relevant, but I wasted a few hours solving it and maybe it will save someone's time. Check if your app has cellular permissions:
Settings - Your App - Mobile Data

This was exactly the problem in my case.